# AssertionError: query should be unbatched 2D or batched 3D tensor but received 4-D query tensor: Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have this [CCT](https://paperswithcode.com/method/cct) Encoder

```
class CctEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, cct_block_params, num_layers):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, cct_block_params[0][0], kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.blocks = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(num_layers):
            in_channels, out_channels, num_heads, mlp_ratio = cct_block_params[i]
            block = CctBlock(in_channels, out_channels, num_heads, mlp_ratio)
            self.blocks.append(block)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        for block in self.blocks:
            x = block(x)
        return x
```

where the CCTBlock is like:

```
class CctBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, num_heads, mlp_ratio=4.0):
        super().__init__()
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(in_channels)
        self.attn = nn.MultiheadAttention(in_channels, num_heads)
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(in_channels)
        self.mlp = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_channels, int(in_channels * mlp_ratio)),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Linear(int(in_channels * mlp_ratio), out_channels),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x_norm = self.norm1(x)
        attn_output, _ = self.attn(x_norm, x_norm, x_norm)
        x = x + attn_output
        x_norm = self.norm2(x)
        mlp_output = self.mlp(x_norm)
        x = x + mlp_output
        return x
```

Now I also have a CNN decoder.

```
class CnnDecoder(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_channels, num_blocks, out_channels):
    super().__init__()
    self.blocks = nn.ModuleList()
    for i in range(num_blocks):
        self.blocks.append(nn.Conv2d(in_channels, in_channels // 2, kernel_size=3, padding=1))
        in_channels //= 2
    self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

def forward(self, x):
    for block in self.blocks:
        x = F.interpolate(x, scale_factor=2, mode="nearest")
        x = block(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
    x = self.conv(x)
    return x
```

I want to execute this whole thing using the below code. Here, CCT will work as a primary encoder layer and CNN will work as a decoder layer.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class InpaintingModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, cct_block_params=((576, 128, 8, 2.0),) * 5, num_blocks=5):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = CctEncoder(3, cct_block_params, num_layers=len(cct_block_params))
        self.grid_generator = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(512, 1024, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(1024, 2048, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(2048, 1024, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )
        self.decoder = CnnDecoder(1024, num_blocks, out_channels=3)
        self.mask_conv = nn.Conv2d(3, 1, kernel_size=1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x, mask):
        encoded_x = self.encoder(x)
        batch_size, channels, height, width = encoded_x.size()
        mask = F.interpolate(mask, size=(height, width), mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)
        mask = self.sigmoid(self.mask_conv(mask))
        masked_encoded_x = encoded_x * mask
        grid = self.grid_generator(mask.unsqueeze(1))
        grid = grid.expand(batch_size, -1, -1, -1)
        deformed_masked_encoded_x = F.grid_sample(masked_encoded_x, grid, mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)
        decoded_x = self.decoder(deformed_masked_encoded_x)
        return decoded_x
```

I am getting the following error while running this model.

```
AssertionError: query should be unbatched 2D or batched 3D tensor but received 4-D query tensor
```

[Traceback](https://gist.github.com/lepotatoguy/a137a748b5a35d3b14ade0c563ab6e65)

[Full code](https://gist.github.com/lepotatoguy/12aa82874503f986621b35d51a608d80)

What should I do in this case? Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Did you check the shapes of the data you feed into the model, you seem to be giving 4D input where it should be 3D.